# Openshift: Authentication failed with private GitLab repo as a dependency

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab, openshift

I'm trying to build and deploy a private node project, hosted in GitLab (Enterprise edition).

It has another private repository as an npm dependency, and it fails every time it tries to install npm dependencies.

I configured my private and public SSH keys in both Openshift and Gitlab. It successfully clones my project (its repository URL is in SSH format), but it seems like the same keys can't be used when installing dependencies, regardless of their URL being `git+ssh` or `git+https`.

There are two different errors I get:

- **When the dependency is `git+ssh://git@mygitlabdomain.com:path/to/project.git`:**

  ```
  Host Key verification failed.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  ```
- **When the dependency is `git+https://mygitlabdomain.com/path/to/project`:**

  ```
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://mygitlabdomain.com/path/to/project/'
  ```

I have read multiple threads about using private repositories as dependencies but none mentioned these errors.

Do you have an idea of why it happens? Thanks!

Comment: You should configure ssh key which will be used by package manager, e.g. ~/.ssh/config or ssh-agent which is used in resolving dependencies phase. You should clarify what do you configure in openshift, but I suppose it's builder's key for cloning.

Comment: @Oligzeev How do I configure ssh key for npm from the web console? Changing the build secret for the build seem to do nothing. About what I did, I added a source secret to the build.

Comment: It's depends on your builder's image stream, but you should do following steps: 1. Create secret with ssh-key; 2. Add it to build config (like https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-in-the-buildconfig) with required destinationDir; 3. Modify ~/.ssh/config in your image stream - you can do it with mounting configMap or .s2i/assemble script (see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/s2i.html)